# 'Running Android Lint' error everytime I save in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm working on an Android project.  Any time I edit and save an XML File I get this error:

> "'Running Android Lint' has encountered a problem.    Failed".

Then When I click on "Details" button, this pops up. "Failed
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"  I just switched to Eclipse Android Neon and am using an old workspace that always worked before.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

```
Error Log:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.eclipse.andmore.internal.lint.EclipseLintClient$1.getNameLocation(EclipseLintClient.java:300)
    at com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.XmlContext.getNameLocation(XmlContext.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.RtlDetector.visitAttribute(RtlDetector.java:527)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.ResourceVisitor.visitElement(ResourceVisitor.java:197)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.ResourceVisitor.visitElement(ResourceVisitor.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.ResourceVisitor.visitFile(ResourceVisitor.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkIndividualResources(LintDriver.java:1765)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:1020)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:904)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:433)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.andmore.internal.lint.LintJob.run(LintJob.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```